# How do I get the current url inside a firebug extension?

Tags: firebug, firefox-addon

How do I get the current url inside a firebug extension when for example pressing a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that mean you create an extension for Firebug? I am not sure about that, but in extensions for Firefox you can get it with

```
window.content.document.location
```

Sorry if I misunderstood the question, it is not totally clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just hover the element and right click to select "Inspect Element" to view details.